# Linking a site altered by custom CSS stylesheet to others for demo?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I want to be able to send someone a link to demonstrate proposed design changes through a custom stylesheet.

So, lets say I had custom CSS to redesign the look of nytimes.com and I wanted to demo those changes to others by showing the site with the custom stylings applied.

On my own browser, I use the in-browser developer tools or an extension like stylish for Firefox or stylebot for Chrome to save those changes.  Though for someone who doesn't have knowledge of CSS, I want a solution that doesn't involve them installing one of these and copying and pasting the custom CSS.

**To Clarify:** This is for a website of which I do not have access to edit. I am unable to access the source code and apply an alternative stylesheet.

Comment: <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink"
 href="http://example.com/css/pink.css">

Comment: That's what PDFs are for.

Comment: http://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/CSS-Style-Switcher-A-quick-and-dirty-how-to.aspx

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/alternate

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a low-tech solution might be best: As you don't have access to edit the original, save a copy of it to your local filesystem and then tinker with the CSS.

When done, send the files to the recipient of the demo instead of a link, or, upload them to your own webserver and send a link to that copy.